# Need help on Apache htaccess redirect rule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect from path

```
 /articles/20090425-swine-flu-kills.html
```

to

```
 /2009/04/swine-flu-kills.html
```

In the original path, the digits after articles are the dates in yyyymmdd format. This to convert to "/yyyy/mm/" in the new path.

I suppose need some regex but I am not sure how. Would appreciate help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/(\d{4})(\d\d)\d\d-(.*)$ /$1/$2/$3
```

This matches:

- `^articles/`: Strings starting with "articles/"
- `(\d{4})`: 4 digits into $1 (the year)
- `(\d\d)`: 2 digits into $2 (the month)
- `\d\d-`: 2 digits & dash (edit: missed the leading dash)
- `(.*)$`: The rest of the URL into $3

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^articles/(\d{4})(\d\d)\d\d\-(.+)$ /$1/$2/$3
```

Would be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks! I will try out both. Only one character difference, to me :-)